# JQuery Validation Not working after page refresh (Jquery Mobile)

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-validate

I have a Jquery Mobile/ asp.net mvc4 application. After the first page, subsequent pages are called by Jquery mobile using Ajax requests. Now, I used JQuery validator plugin to perform validation on my forms, the validation is working fine first time(ie when loaded using ajax calls) but when a page is refreshed/reloaded the validation is not working. Any idea why this is happening? As this is a mobile web application there is a possibility users might refresh pages.

this is the validation code I have used:

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
// jquery form validation function
$(function () {
    $("#permissionRequestForm").validate({
        errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
            if (element.attr("name") === "fromTimeHH" || element.attr("name") === "toTimeHH" || element.attr("name") === "fromTimeMM" || element.attr("name") === "toTimeMM") {
                error.insertAfter($(element).parent());
            } else {
                error.insertAfter(element);
            }
        },

        //custom validation messages
        messages: {
            fromDate: "Choose From Date",
            toDate: " Choose To Date",
            fromTimeHH: "Choose From Time",
            fromTimeMM: "",
            toTimeHH: "Choose To Time",
            toTimeMM: "",
            permissionTypeOne: "Select Permission Type",
            permissionTypeTwo: "Select Permission Type",
            approverList: "Select Approver",
            reasonLeave: "Enter a Valid Reason"
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Show as your code, there's not much we can do without it. But let me ask you a question, are you using document ready state to initialize a validation plugin or are you using a pageshow event (or any other page event) ? Also are you using multi html page format or 1 html with multiple pages?

Comment: Hi, will try to add some code, I'm not using any events, and its multi html page format not single html.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a wild guess because code sample was not provided, I presume you have used:

```
$(document).ready(function() {    

});
```

to initialize a validator plugin what is a common practice for jquery. Unfortunately document ready can not be used with jQuery Mobile.

Also do not use :

```
$(function () {

});
```

With jQuery Mobile.

Validator plugin should be initialized in page show event, like this:

```
$('#index').live('pageshow',function(e,data){    
    $.validator.addMethod("valueNotEquals", function(value, element, arg){
        return arg != value;
    }, "");

    $("#form1").validate({
        rules: {
            select_list : {valueNotEquals: "default"},  
        },
        messages: {  
            select_list : { valueNotEquals: "You must select a value" }
        },        
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            alert($('#form1').valid());
            form.submit();
        }
    });   
});
```

And here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/AZPhK/. No matter how much time you close and return to first page, every time page is shown validator will initialize.

**EDIT :**

IF you are using multi html page format put this code only into wanted page, or better, create a new js file, put this code (all all your custom js code) in it and share it among all html pages.

Comment: Thank you sir! Worked great after using the live event :)

Comment: In the expamle given, if we submit a form without selecting any value, then there will be error mesage, and after that when we will move to next page and comes to previous page then there is still an error message showing, how can we resolve that?